# How to set up thousands of VLANs on ISC DHCP-4.1.1-P1 server?

Tags: centos, vlan, isc-dhcpd

I have been attempting to set up a DHCP server using ISC DHCP-4.1.1-P1 compiled on CentOS 6.7

The idea is to have multiple thousands of VLANs.
I have started small. I have no issue doing ifup on hundreds of `ifcfg-eth0.*` interfaces and then doing `service dhcpd restart`.
The server is then stable.

However, as soon as I try to get past 1024 VLANs, I seem to hit a few limitations. Out of the box (without any tweaks to the source code or to the system settings, such as `ulimit -Sn` or `__FD_SETSIZE`), the service will not start because of a max number of sockets reached. At best, the service starts but then the kernel kills it immediately (`general protection error`).

What would be the correct way of addressing the issue ? I think I identified a file descriptor number `FD_SETSIZE` as a potential lead to the solution.

History:

- I've used `ulimit -Sn 2048`

Thanks for your time.

Other discussions elsewhere : [ars technica](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1210655)

[update: found out the service invoked was still 4.1.1, and not 4.3.3 which I had installed - I seem to have it under control with 4.3.3. Technically, it's not really solved as I can't trace the origin of the problem in 4.1.1.]